# Coverting list of Coordinates to list of tuples

Tags: python, list, for-loop, tuples, coordinates

I'm trying to covert a list of coordinates to a list of tuples:

from:

```
a_list = ['56,78','72,67','55,66']
```

to:

```
list_of_tuples = [(56,78),(72,67),(55,66)]
```

I've tried doing a for, in loop to convert each element in a_list to a tuple however the output is in the form:

```
list_of_tuples = [('5', '6', '7', '8'), ('7', '2', '6', '7'), ('5', '5', '6', '6')]
```

Any help on what I am doing wrong here would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: Fixed the expected output, no spaces between coordinates and tuples.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use list comprehension:

```
result = [tuple(map(int,element.split(','))) for element in a_list]
```

edit: shorter version by @Lol4t0

As mentioned the spaces between the elements come from printing the list. There are no actual "spaces" in the data structure. However, if you wish to print your list without any spaces you can do:

```
print str(result).replace(" ","")
```

Comment: Still too long: `[tuple(map(int, e.split(','))) for e in a_list]`

Comment: The spaces are automatically set when printing a list. You can print your expected output list `list_of_tuples` to see what I mean. It's still going to print `[(56, 78), (72, 67), (55, 66)]`

Answer (score 1):

Use a list comprehension, `split` the items and convert each subitem to `int` using `map`:

```
>>> result = [map(int, item.split(',')) for item in a_list ]
>>> result
[(56, 78), (72, 67), (55,66)]
```

On python 3.x, you should convert the `map` object to a `tuple`

```
>>> result = [tuple(map(int, item.split(','))) for item in a_list ]
```

Comment: Spaces are only for readability. They don't mean a thing in this case.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Our lecturer always stresses out over spaces, I guess he rubbed off on me.

Answer (score 1):

Nice and simple, here it is

```
    a_list = ['56,78','72,67','55,66']

    result = []
    for coord in a_list:
        result.append(tuple([int(x) for x in coord.split(',')]))

    print(str(result).replace(" ", ""))

    # Output

    [(56,78),(72,67),(55,66)]
```

The first way I thought of was this:

```
    a_list = ['56,78','72,67','55,66']

    int_list = []
    for coord in a_list:
        for x in coord.split(','):
            int_list.append(int(x))

    result = []
    for i in range(0, len(int_list), 2):
        result.append((int_list[i], int_list[i+1]))

    print(str(result).replace(" ", ""))

    # Output

    [(56,78),(72,67),(55,66)]
```

This way is also good if your new to python and want to solve this sort of problem with more procedure. My mindset for this was to just put all the coordinates into a list and group them into pairs at every second integer.

I hope this helps.

Comment: @user6394303 I modified the last line to take away whitespaces. Is that correct for the edit?

Comment: No worries, if you like the answer, give it an upvote for future users.

Comment: I tried but haven't accumulated 15 reputation yet :(