# Converting text file to list then finding items with in a list, how to fix my code?

Tags: python, list, exception, try-catch, median

So I'm doing a project and I'm struggling with it. 
I need to convert the text file to a list then:

- find the smallest value USING LIST FUNCTION(S)
- find largest value USING LIST FUNCTION(S)
- find number of values read USING LIST FUNCTION(S)
- The average of the value read.
- The median value of the list
- The most frequently occurring value in the list, and how many times it occurred.
- The values read from the file, sans duplicates, in DESCENDING order.

  ```
  try: 
      listFile = open('input.txt','r')
      line = listFile.readline()
      listFile.write(line)
      read += 1 
      total += line
      listFile.sort()

      smallest = min in line
      largest = max in line
      average = (total/read)

      import listFile
      middle = listFile.median

      outputInfo = open('output.txt','w')
      outputInfo.write('The smallest value is:',smallest)
      outputInfo.write('The largest value is:',largest)
      outputInfo.write('The number of values read is:',read)
      outputInfo.write('The median of the values read is',middle)

      close('input.txt')

  except IOError: 
      print('The file could not be found/read')
  except ValueError: 
      print('This value is not accepted')
  except: 
      print('An error occured while trying to run the program')
  ```

Comment: what is the file format?

Comment: its a python file but it opening and writing to a text file

Comment: not the file, how is the array represented? `1 2 3 4 5`, `1, 2, 3, 4, 5` or `1-2-3-4-5`?

Comment: Well the file has no known values or anything it just reading the file and finding everything

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Coverting list of Coordinates to list of tuples](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37498669/coverting-list-of-coordinates-to-list-of-tuples)

Answer (score 1):

Considering you have an array `arr`:

```
smallest = min(arr)
largest = max(arr)
sum_of_array = sum(arr)
number_of_elements = len(arr)

import statistics
average = statistics.mean(arr)
median= statistics.median(arr)
```

---

About the file, it's unclear how are the values saved. I'll assume for a space-separated list file, saved inside `data.txt` like

```
2 5 34 78 2 89 345 6 54 7 667 87 34
```

then creating the array would go like

```
arr = sorted([int(x) for x in open('data.txt').read().split()])
```

Comment: How would i do the median with an array?

Comment: would i still need to sort it?

Comment: also when i run or try to it tells me this

Comment: /usr/bin/python: can't find '__main__' module in ''

Comment: So where would i put that in my file?

Comment: replace your file. take the code in that dump and run it. save a space separated list into the file `data.txt` in the same directory and watch

Comment: Okay i also need to write this to an output file